# AWS EC2 Opendatasource to the same server - OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: openrowset

Trying to run a Opendatasource query to point to the same server as the source server in AWS EC2, I got this message intermittently (once out of about 20 times, the other 19 times do get results back).   Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Error:

```
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)"
```

Query:

```
select top 10 *
from OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI11','User ID=test;Password=test;Data Source=10.11.5.11').[test].dbo.test
```

Comment: Why would you want such a loopback connection anyway?

Answer (score 0):

We discovered SQLNCLI11 driver does not work well in AWS EC2.  We are using msoledbsql driver and the issue went away,  thanks everyone!